# If mergesort takes 30 sec to sort 64 elements in worst case, how many elements can be sorted at worst case by using it in 6 minutes?

Tags: algorithms, mergesort

## To sort 64 elements

Time required is $n*log_2{n}$ units

The equivalent posteriori time is 30 sec.

## In 6 minutes

I get 768 elements sorted.

But the answer is not 768 and is instead 512, I wonder why?

Comment: Compare log 64 and log 512.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the fact that these calculations make no sense in real world, here is what we get:

$n \cdot log_2 n \cdot T = 30$

where $T$ is the time for single operation. We substitute $n=64$ and we get

$64 \cdot 6 \cdot T = 30$

this gives $T=0.078125$

We can now solve the following:

$n \cdot log_2n \cdot 0.078125 = 360$

You can verify the solution is $512$.

Answer (score 1):

6 minutes to 30 seconds is a factor of 12, so you want:
$$ \frac{N\cdot\text{log}(N)}{64\cdot\text{log}(64)} = 12 $$
You can easily verify that for N=512, the result is indeed 12. For N=768 the result is 19.17, which is the wrong answer. Note that it doesn't matter which logarithm (binary, natural, ...) you use, the result is always the same.

While verifying the equation for a given N is easy, finding N is much harder. You can just try different values of N until you find one where the result is 12. You would have found that N=768 is too large (result 19.17) and tried smaller values until you found the correct one.